# django-celery-beat PeriodicTask not firing

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I have a project using django-celery-beat, celery, and reds. For some reason one specific task out of many in my entire project never fires, with no errors or anything.

- I've verified that it's autodetected and showing up in the Django Admin dropdown and is registered with @app.task.
- I've tried deleting and recreating the task.
- I've tried creating the PeriodicTask programmatically instead of via the Admin.
- I've tried setting the last_run_at to `start_time - interval`
- I've tried using a crontab interval.
- I've made sure it's enabled and points to a correct task name.

Are there any reasons why this might be happening? It appears to be just straight up ignored.

Comment: Did you check your CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE if you already have one ?